# Role based access control for Kibana and Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-x-pack, role-based-access-control

I am new to Elastic and Kibana. Using Version **6.2.4**.
I have installed the ELK stack with the X-pack enabled on it.
Now I have Kibana working on port 5601 with authentication and elastic working on 9200 with authentication.

Here is what I want to achieve by Kibana:

- Get visualisations for the data [*I know this can be done*]
- Give different roles to different users
- Based on role, restrict the user access for data
- Example users will be Admin, user and anonymous user

Can this be done using Kibana? If No, what wrong I am expecting?

If yes, then is this the correct way, please check below:

```
curl -XPOST -u elastic 'localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/ingestadmin' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "password" : "tudip123",
  "full_name" : "Ingest Admin",
  "email" : "ingest.admin@xyz.com",
  "roles" : [ "ingest_admin" ]
}'
```

Comment: so, is it working for you or not? what did you try?

Comment: @Mysterion
It is working but I want to know if my approach is correct?

Comment: approach in what? im not sure i understand

Comment: @Mysterion
I have posted few questions above, please answer those...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, thanks, [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

I searched the web and got all my answers:

**Questions:**

> - Get visualizations for the data
> - Give different roles to different users
> - Based on the role, restrict the user access to data
> - Example users will be Admin, user and anonymous user
>
> Can this be done using Kibana?

**Answer:**

- **Yes it can be done**

> If yes, then is this the correct way, please check below:

*>>The way stated to create the user and role above in the question is correct, in fact, Kibana provides you the UI to do it in an easy way. [Management tab]*

**Conclusion:**

*We can add role-based access to the data using roles and privileges in Kibana. Below are few links that helped me:*

1. [Configuring Role-based Access Control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/authorization.html#authorization)
2. [Built-in Roles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/built-in-roles.html)
3. [Defining Roles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/defining-roles.html)

You can get next link from the page itself. (Check the right bottom corner)